# A $\sigma$ algebra at most of numerable cardinality is finite.

Tags: real-analysis, probability, probability-theory, measure-theory

Let $\mathcal{A}$ a $\sigma$ algebra at most of numerable cardinality (i.e $|\mathcal{A}|\leq  \aleph_0$). Show that $\mathcal{A}$ is finite.

I try to build a disjoint subcollection of $\mathcal A$ to try this exercise but I can not think what this subcollection can be.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Well if you line up all the sets in your sigma algebra, like so: $E_1, E_2, \dots$, what are the 'smallest sets' we can obtain from these by the actions of union, intersection, or complement?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose that $\mathcal A$ is a $\sigma$-algebra of subsets of the set $X$. Suppose further that $\mathcal B$ is a countably infinite subcollection of $\mathcal A$.  For each $x\in X$, consider the sets
$$E_x=\bigcap\{E\in\mathcal B:x\in E\}.$$
To show that $\{E_x:x\in X\}$ is a infinite disjoint subcollection, look at the relation $\sim$ on $X$ given by $x\sim y$ iff $y\in E_x$.

Comment: @Aweygan and how conclude that $\mathcal{A}$ is finite?

Comment: @LuisPrado It doesn't.  This is used to show the contrapositive, i.e., if $\mathcal A$ is infinite, then $|\mathcal A|>\aleph_0$.

Comment: exactly I just thought this way ... but because $|\mathcal{A}|>\aleph_0$.?

Comment: $\cup_{x\in X} E_x\subseteq \mathcal{A}$ and?

Comment: If you can show that $\{E_x:x\in X\}$ is infinite and $E_x\cap E_y=\varnothing$ when $E_x\neq E_y$, then the collection of all finite unions of the $E_x$ is an uncountable subcollection of $\mathcal A$.

Comment: And it isn't true that $\cup_{x\in X} E_x$ is a subset of $\mathcal A$.  It is a subset of $X$, but it may not even be an element of $\mathcal A$.